# JasperReports server REST call with runtime datasource

Tags: rest, runtime, datasource, jasperserver

I would like to make a REST call to a report and provide the datasource as a parameter at runtime such as this:

http://somereporthost.com:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/Recently_Created?**datasource=ds_test**&user=doej&begin_date=2012-12-04

Given this example, in the use case I have in mind, ds_test would already exist as would others (ds_test2, ds_test3) so that any datasource could be specified at runtime.

Is it possible to specify a datasource at runtime?

I have seen one thread which includes changing the datasource associated with a particular report but unless I misunderstood the solution, I see potential race-condition issues.

I saw another one which creates a copy of the report on the fly with the desired datasource but I think this would create the need for some housekeeping when reports are updated and seems to be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using release 6.2 of JasperReports Server. I think the way this is supposed to work is by referencing user attributes, and defining as many execution users as datasources you need.

Please take a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37926230/5731158