# Is it possible for a report to have a dynamic data source connection based on users in JasperReports Server?

Tags: jasper-reports, datasource, jasperserver

Can we give dynamic data source connection ( expression ) for a report  based on users in *JasperReports Server*?

Answer (score 1):

At least for release 6.2 **yes**. Please take a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37926230/5731158

I'm not sure since which version they started allowing to reference attributes in datasource definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The Jasper Professional Services handled this via "monkey patching"  `com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcReportDataSourceServiceFactory` (meaning compile it and place it in `WEB-INF/classes` to overwrite the standard one) and adding in dynamic logic.

I don't think this is "proper" but it does work. The majority of the logic is in the `createService` method. I'd share it but it has logic specific to our company.