# How to access database in jasperreports server without manually keying in parameter data

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I published my reports from Jasper Studio to Jasper Server. They are working perfectly but I need to input all the parameters manually. How can I access the database in such a way that I can select data possibly through a dropdown list or something instead of manually keying in the data? I am using Windows SQL Server for my database.

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining a data source whose connection settings depend on user's attributes, and at runtime select the user that executes the report so it gets the data from a different connection (using the same data source definition).

You can take a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37926230/5731158